# How do I convert scale bars after a 2d FFT?

Tags: numpy, fft

I'm currently writing something which will compute the 2d FFT of an image and pick out certain peaks in the magnitude spectrum. My images all have scales on the x and y axis in nm but I'm struggling to understand how I would convert from my length scales to frequencies.

I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding something simple here but I can't find anything on the subject that seems relevant.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Fourier Transform converts data from the time domain into the frequency domain ... the inverse Fourier Transform does the opposite namely converts from frequency domain into the time domain representation ...  when you feed data into one of these transforms the original scales become moot ... I suggest you research the terms mentioned here ... Fourier Transform is a vast body of work where you can invest years of effort learning its possibilities do not attempt to skim over quickly ... make the strategic decision whether your data begins in the time domain or freq domain and go from there

Answer (score 0):

### Brief overview of FFT

Remember [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) is just a *Fast* version of the *Discrete Fourier Transform* algorithm. It transforms data back and forth between the signals original domain (which could be either time or space) and its corresponding frequency domain. In case of images, you are talking about spatial frequency.

### Spatial frequency

Spatial frequency is similar to regular temporal frequency. But it has units of `m⁻¹` rather than `s⁻¹`.

Remember that from [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) the highest frequency component is equal to **half** of the sampling rate. In time frequency, this means that if you are sampling at `1000Hz` the highest signal frequency you can sample is `500Hz`. In spatial domain, this is equivalent. If you are sampling every milimetre (`1000m⁻¹`) your signal can only contain the highest frequency of `500m⁻¹` (wavelength of `2mm`).

You can sort of picture it by imagining you sample `1, -1, 1, -1 ...`  at every `1mm`, the wave clearly repeats every `2mm`.

The smallest frequency component is going to depend on the length of the signal. Clearly if you have a `1s` sample, the smallest frequency bin you can detect is `1Hz`. As you have probably already noticed, same applies to spatial frequencies.

Now you could look at your sampling rate, and your signal length and work out the frequency spacing and align for the shifted FFT signal... But `numpy` already provides a very powerful method for generating your frequency axis [`numpy.fft.fftfreq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html). You give it the length of your signal `n` and sample spacing `d` and it will provide you with the correctly scaled and spaced frequency axis.

So in your case where you have an `x` x `y` image with pixels every `nm` you would generate your x and y spatial frequency axis like this:

```
d = 1e-9 # Sample spacing is 1nm
y, x = image.shape # Get the y and x size of your input image (assuming its just 2D)
y_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(y, d)
x_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(x, d)
```

### Frequency order

Remember that by default, the output of a FFT is shifted so the coefficients start at DC, continue to highest frequency and then wrap to the negative frequencies

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

`fftfreq` outputs the frequencie axis in the same way. In case you want to reorder the axis, us [`np.fft.fftshift`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html). This will reorder the frequencies to a more logical order like this:

```
[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This also works for 2D FFT. Basically your code would look something like this:

```
image_f = np.fft.fft2(image) # 2D FFT of image
image_fs = np.fft.fftshift(image_f) # shift the FFT of the image

d = 1e-9 # Sampling rate is 1/1nm
y, x = image.shape # Get the y and x size of your input image (assuming its just 2D)
# Compute the shifted Spacial Frequency axis with units m⁻¹
y_freq = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(y, d))
x_freq = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(x, d)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Plot the absolute of the 2D FFT. Set the axis extent to the min/max values for x and y freq axis
# Note, in imshow, you actually don't really need the full freq axis, just the limits
ax.imshow(np.abs(image_fs), origin='lower', extent=[x_freq[0], x_freq[-1], y_freq[0], y_freq[-1]])
```

Comment: You are welcome, I just noticed, I made a mistake, I thought `fftfreq` takes the sampling frequency as its parameter while it actually takes the sample spacing. I corrected it above. They are just the inverse of each other. `sr = 1/d`